# Add EPSG:3857 geometries to map using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, coordinate-system

Right now Leaflet can only add geometries with latitude and longitude values onto the map.

If we have a EPSG:3857 point, whose x=-11819829 and y=4200860, how can I add it onto the map?

If this point needs to be unprojected as geographical coordinates, how to implement it?

Comment: have a look at `cs2cs` from the [tag:proj4] library and tools project. There are some online conversion tools using it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the right projection in mind? [According to SpatialReference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/), you're talking about **Web Mercator** which, as its name implies, has (decimal) degrees as linear units. EPSG 3857 is, in fact, [the default projection used by Leaflet and most web mapping frameworks](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#projections-l.projection.sphericalmercator). As the underlying SRS is WGS84, you should be able to treat your EPSG 3857 coordinates as unprojected geographical coordinates (GCS WGS84).

Comment: I was talking about **Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)**, which is EPSG:3857. I have tried _L.Projection.SphericalMercator.unproject_ and _map.unproject_. Both failed.

Comment: @Arthur, the WKT has 2 UNIT objects. One is for the GeoCRS, and the other for the Projected CRS. The overall unit is in metres. Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) is the Esri name for EPSG:3857.

Comment: @GChen, have you seen this doc: http://developer.tomtom.com/docs/read/map_toolkit/javascript_sdk_2_0/Migration_Guide

Comment: @mkennedy This document is very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. EPSG:3857 uses meters as the unit, not degrees.

Comment: It's complicated. See also: [How to access Leaflet EPSG:3857 coordinates?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/153849/13692).