# How to access Leaflet EPSG:3857 coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, coordinates, epsg

I read [everywhere](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#defined-crs-l.crs.epsg3857) that Leaflet is internally using a spherical web mercator (EPSG:3857), but whatever I try I get either Lat/Lon (EPSG:4326) or strange coordinates I dont understand:

```
map.getBounds().getNorthEast();          // LatLng(52.5262, 13.44907)
map.getPixelBounds().getTopRight();      // Point(2253845, 1375425) ???
map.getPixelOrigin();                    // Point(2252165, 1375425) ???
```

Let's try to project the spherical mercator:

```
L.Projection.SphericalMercator.project(
    map.getBounds().getNorthEast()
);                                       // Point(0.23473, 1.08117) !?!
```

All right, there is a [known bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/95857/13692) in Leaflet 0.7.3, so let's add the earth radius:

```
L.point(
    L.Projection.SphericalMercator.project(
        map.getBounds().getNorthEast()
    ).x * 6378137.0,
    L.Projection.SphericalMercator.project(
        map.getBounds().getNorthEast()
    ).y * 6378137.0
);                                       // Point(1497143.40914, 6895833.38915)
```

So, really, is it so hard to get the default projection coordinates of my map? Why do I have to call `project()` at all? What did I miss?

I am using leaflet 0.7.3 and did not change the CRS, using [default](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-crs) EPSG:3857. Any ideas?

How to access Leaflet EPSG:3857 coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got an answer on [github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4146):

> Internally, Leaflet transforms EPSG:4326 coordinates to pixel coordinates. These pixel coordinates are the EPSG:3857 coordinates divided by a power of 2 (and then rounded).
>
> It might be possible to fetch some of these coordinates (look at methods like `L.Map.latLngToLayerPoint`) and then multiply stuff given the zoom level, but beware of rounding errors.

So my assumption EPSG:3857 is the default was wrong.